# openrdf-sesame SPARQLResultsXMLWriter and XSL

Tags: xslt, jena, sesame

how can i add xsl stylesheet in XML out stream provided by SPARQLResultsXMLWriter?

```
RepositoryConnection con = repository.getConnection();
SPARQLResultsXMLWriter sparqlWriter = new SPARQLResultsXMLWriter(out);
   try {
       TupleQuery query = con.prepareTupleQuery(org.openrdf.query.QueryLanguage.SPARQL, qs);
       query.evaluate(sparqlWriter);
   } 
   finally {
       con.close();
   }
```

I'm looking for something like this,

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter.outputAsXML(outStream,resulSet,**xslFilePath**);
```

provided by Jena Framework... the similar for Sesame

Thanks,
Enzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Sesame SPARQLResultsXMLWriter does not have an option for this. However, it should be fairly easy to customize it. What you need to do is create a subclass of the class `info.aduna.xml.XMLWriter` (which is a utility class for correctly formatted XML that is used by the SPARQLResultsXMLWriter internally). In this subclass, add a getter/setter to specify the stylesheet link, and then override the startDocument method like so:

```
public class MyXMLWriter extends info.aduna.xml.XMLWriter {

     @Override
     public void startDocument() throws IOException {
         super.startDocument();
         _write("<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\"");
         _write(" href=\"" + getStylesheetRef() + "\"");
         _writeLn("?>");
     }
}
```

Then just supply this customized XMLWriter to your SPARQLResultsXMLWriter and set the stylesheet ref to the correct value:

```
MyXMLWriter writer = new MyXMLWriter(out);
writer.setStylesheetRef("example.xsl");

SPARQLResultsXMLWriter sparqlWriter = new SPARQLResultsXMLWriter(writer);
```

Untested, but fairly confident this should work.

Alternatively, raise a feature request with the Sesame project and/or supply them with a patch.